# Two handed weapons in one hand

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Is it possible to wield a two handed weapon in one hand? If so, what penalties apply? If not, are there circumstances or abilities that would make it possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## It is not generally possible

Absent any special feat, class ability, or what have you, it is not generally possible to wield a two-handed weapon in one hand. You can *carry* one with a single hand, but not fight with it.

#### Larger creatures can weild smaller creatures’ two-handed weapons in one hand

You can wield the two-handed weapon of a creature one size category smaller than yourself at a −2 penalty. That means you, if we assume you are a Medium creature, could wield a Small two-handed weapon one-handed at a −2 penalty. On average, you generally see a ~1 damage increase for a two-handed weapon over a one-handed weapon, which is not worth a −2 penalty.

Unfortunately, most feats aimed at allowing you to use inappropriately sized weapons without penalty focus on wielding *larger* weapons. I cannot find any in *Pathfinder* that work. In 3.5, there were the [“web enhancement” kobolds](https://web.archive.org/web/20210515093955/http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/we/20060420a), but as far as I know the Slight Build feature, unique to those kobolds, was literally the only thing that could accomplish it.

## Wielding weapons with both hands is typically a *good* thing

Really must be mentioned: because of the 1½ Str to damage, wielding weapons with both hands is simply *better* than wielding it in one hand, typically even accounting for the loss of shield or a second weapon.

There may be reasons other than damage that you’re interested in this, but I wanted to point it out.

Comment: Indeed, the player in question wants to gain the magical benefits of the particular 2h weapon, but not have to sacrifice his magical shield.

Comment: @EricB I'd turn it into a little side-quest to get the sword modified so that it can be used that way. Or the shield, for that matter. The *animated* property is still a thing in *Pathfinder*, right?

Comment: The damage increase might not be worth the penalty but sometimes wielding two usually-two-handed weapons is nice. Double wielding small spiked chains anyone?

Comment: @Zachiel Piling penalties on penalties so you never hit anything? Not my idea of nice. Besides, numerous light or one-handed weapons (kusari-gama, spinning sword, whip-dagger) exist that are effectively spiked chains that don't take penalties for that.

Comment: @Zachiel I'm pretty sure an inappropriately undersized weapon A) were it before is no longer a reach weapon and B) can't be used with the feat Weapon Finesse. I mean, there might still be benefits, but they are few.

Comment: @HeyICanChan spiked chains are still reach weapons for small characters, due to how medium and small characters have both the same space and reach. I don't see why B, but I can see a DM houseruling that way.

Comment: @Zachiel Yeah, a Small spiked chain is a reach weapon for a Small creature, but I'm not sure that makes a Small spiked chain a reach weapon for a Medium character. Yeah, I know that's weird. Also, I don't know why B either except that Weapon Finesse mandates you use a weapon "made for a creature of your size."

Comment: Extra damage is a fine incentive, to be sure. I was wondering about this one-handed tactic only because of lusting for the occasional enhanced shield in a pile of swag

Answer (score 5):

Add on to KRyan's wonderful answer.

The only class that can wield 2 handed weapons in 1 hand is the [Titan Mauler (Barbarian archetype)](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/barbarian/archetypes/paizo---barbarian-archetypes/titan-mauler)

> Jotungrip (Ex)
>
> At 2nd level, a titan mauler may choose to wield a two-handed melee
>   weapon in one hand with a –2 penalty on attack rolls while doing so.
>   The weapon must be appropriately sized for her, and it is treated as
>   one-handed when determining the effect of Power Attack, Strength bonus
>   to damage, and the like.

Comment: +1 for being an accurate statement and a previously-unmentioned option, but *good god* is it a terrible option. Please, no one ever do this.